# Create a List of Products which miss a specific Version

Tags: sql

I have to create a list of products from `ProductTable`. The field which I am filtering is the `VersionID`.
So I have a Table of `ProductIDs` and `VersionIDs`. The Problem is that for every Version there is an entry in the database e.g.

```
ProductID | VersionID
1         | x
1         | y
1         | z
2         | y
```

The Product which contains Version x should not show up on this list, so in this Case only Product 2 should be listed.
Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work about your attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try using a subquery where you get all ProdcutID that you dont want

```
select ProdcutID from PRODUCTTABLE where VersionID = x
```

and filter your query with not in subquery like this

```
select * 
from PRODUCTTABLE 
where ProdcutID not in (select ProdcutID 
      from PRODUCTTABLE 
      where VersionID = x)
```

Comment: @Marcao13 than please mark my answer as correct so I can get some rep :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM ProductTable p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ProductTable p2 WHERE p2.ProductId = p.ProductId AND Version = x)
```

In a nutshell we select all products where another query for the *same* product -- check out where we use `p` and `p2` -- with a specific version `x` does not yield a result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single pass (no sub-query, etc), by aggregating and checking the contents of the aggregate don't contain an `'x'`

```
SELECT
  ProductID
FROM
  ProductTable
GROUP BY
  ProductID
HAVING
  MAX(CASE WHEN VersionID = 'x' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```